# google classroom Invitation accept method return a NOT-FOUND

Tags: google-api, google-apis-explorer, google-classroom

I have invited a google account as a student to my course and listing the invitations using **LIST** method returns the invitationId , courseId , Role(Listing is done from the senders google account). But if i accept the invitation from the invited users account with the invitation id. 
It returns the following :

```
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Requested entity was not found.",
    "status": "NOT_FOUND"
  }
}
```

I am also not able to **GET** the invitation from the invited users account.
I am able to **GET** the invitation only from the senders account.

what is the issue I am facing and how can i solve it?

Comment: I have the same problem here

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit the Class membership settings in your Google Admin. It's probably configured to only allow users in your domain.

To change this, go to your Google Admin [console](https://admin.google.com) and then `Apps > Additional Google services > Settings for Classroom > Class settings` and in `"Who can join classes in your domain"` set it to `"Any user"`

Take into account that changes can take 24h to propagate to all users.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but `"Who can join classes in your domain"` is already set it to `"Any user"` . Still it does not work. I am not able to accept the invitation.

Comment: I see. I recomend you to contact [G Suite](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en). In my tests, I could include a Gmail student in my domain, but I had to change that option first.

Comment: @RaagulRN did you have any luck with this?

Comment: @zaPlayer No I had to change the whole logic just because of this problem.
Could not find a solution.